# .War updates for Jboss

Tags: java, jboss, jsp

There is a .war file running well in JBoss environment. I need to update some little logic in some of the .jsp files.

The steps I followed was

1. First I change the extension to .zip extract out a particular .jsp file
2. Then I make some small changes to it.
3. I kept the original war file and following this link How to unpackage and repackage a WAR file and the suggestion in it say "Non programmatically, you can just open the archive using the 7zip UI to add/remove or extract/replace files without the structure changing. I didn't know it was a problem using other things until now :)".

I tried this mechanism but I got the following error. Problem now I would like to solve this with minimal change ? What is the best possible manner?

```
HTTP Status 404 - /tts/login.jsp

type Status report

message /tts/login.jsp

description The requested resource (/tts/login.jsp) is not available.
```

Comment: Could it be possible that you introduced an error in the JSP so that it cannot be recompiled anymore? Do you find any error messages in the log related to the redeployment or first access of that jsp?

Comment: Nope I purpose did not change I just change the username to usernamee. that is all I change. Which log file should I check ? Infact I also ran this command jar -cvf tts.war tts/ also the same issue

Comment: The jboss server logfile, it should be called server.log and by default it lives in a subdirectory called log, of the installation directory. If under some unix-ish OS, you can `tail -F server.log` to see what's going on in realtime.

Comment: Which is the correct method actually to redeploy the .war maybe my method is wrong ?

Comment: The exact proper procedure(s) may depend on the version of the appserver, I'd have a look at the documentation of the server version you use (via http://jboss.org - for version 6 https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.4/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/chap-Application_Deployment.html )

Comment: The problem my jboss is a very old version. Its 4.0.5 ? I tried the tail -F server.log too. I can see this link /usr/local/jboss-4.0.5.GA/server/default/log . In this I can see a lot of log files should I based on these log files ?

Comment: I went to this log file I could see this *.*.*.* - - [26/Aug/2015:19:22:13] "GET /tts/login.jsp HTTP/1.1" 404 997

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27422/discussion-between-user4126382-and-fvu).

Comment: you need to redeploy your application, it sounds like it's been undeployed now (or not updated).

Answer (score 0):

use `undeploy`, `deploy` and `deployment-info` to re-deploy your newly re-packaged `.war` file.